# How to show delete/edit link for the logged in user and not everyone?

Tags: django

I know how I can delete and edit posts in different views, but in one page where there is one post and several answer to this post, how would i link to edit and delete views for all these different users?

Or is is_authenticated only for one user, so they are only able to view their own posts delete/edit links anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's simplest form, you can do this in your templates,

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    Show Edit Link
    Show Delete Link
{% endif %}
```

But then you'd want to show the Edit/Delete link only on the answers by the current logged in user.

You can do that like this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user == answer.creator %}
    Show Edit Link
    Show Delete Link
{% endif %}
```

Finally, you'll also need to make the check in your Edit and Delete views to ensure the user is actually the create of the answer, otherwise anybody can edit/delete any post:

```
def edit_view(request, post_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user == post.creator:
        # edit post
        ...
```

To do that in generic class based views:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.get_object()
        if request.user != post.creator:
            # raise a 403 Forbidden error
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ah so django knows who is logged in and which posts belong to them?

Comment: @ReducedGosling Django knows who is logged in but not which posts belong to whom. You need additional logic for that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! How is this possible if I use built-in class based DeleteView, UpdateView etc?

Comment: @ReducedGosling Updated answer. Although do note that I've written that for `GET` method only. You can adopt the code based on what method your using to delete the answers like `POST` or `DELETE` methods.